# What MySQL table design is better on performance?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have to create a database-application with lots of data. So now I need a good table/database design. I have two in mind but I am open for new ones. First: This is something similar to the data I will have to save:

> Food: **Beef**
>
> Contains:
>
> Brom: Percent: 12% /// Gram: 0.23
>
> Uran: Percent: 1% /// Gram: 0.003
>
> Gold: Percent: 0.03% /// Gram: 0.02
>
> and so on

Now I have two designs in sight at the moment:

> For every element (Brom, Gold, ...) I create a table like "brom_tbl, gold_tbl" and a table in which the name and a global id is displayed (gbl_tbl). When I then want to read all the data I just join it together.

Here's the second one:

> I only have one table looking like this:
>
> name | brom_percent | brom_gram | gold_percent | gold_gram | ...
>
> Beef | 12           | 0.23      | 0.03         | 0.02
>
> And then I would just read everything out.

Would be nice if you could say me what is faster or better.

Thanks :)

Comment: Use one table. And don't use names like `gbl_tbl`, its not MS-DOS.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you have tips for naming tables? Or should I just let it be `gbl`?

Comment: Is "gbl" supposed to mean "global"? Then name it "global" if that makes sense. Better yet, name if "food_metal_content" or whatever the table is about. So that, in 10 years, when somebody is looking through your (then 100 different) tables, they will be able to find the right one. There is no need to use cryptic abrvtns.

Comment: Use real words. There's no reason to write `tbl` instead of `table`. The same applies to variable names as well in your code. Future you, and other developers will thank you for it.

Comment: Ok, thank you both.

Comment: Great, now I'm going to have "gibble tibble" stuck in my head for the rest of the workday.

Comment: @KirkBeard And there's usually no reason to write "table" in a table name at all. `users_table` can just be `users`.

Comment: I suspect the "one table" @C14L is suggesting is not the table of your 1-table design but (from their coment on an answer below "a row for food_name and then metal_percentage and metal_grams rows for each metal". PS You need to learn a lot more about "better" straightforward designs before you need to concern yourself with speed or other aspects of design.

Comment: "table" is a reserved word though.....

Comment: @ceejayoz I absolutely agree with that point. I just used the word "table" as an example. Neither the words "global" or "table" should used here, because they don't really describe the content of the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

What about creating two tables like this:

One for the food..

```
create table Food
(
 FoodId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 Name   varchar(1000)
)
```

And one for the attributes:

```
create table Attributes
(
    AttributeId INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Description varchar(1000),
    FoodId      INT, /* Referencds FoodId in Food table */
    Value       Decimal,
    FOREIGN KEY (FoodId)
       REFERENCES Food(FoodId)
)
```

You could create a Attribute table with the names of the attributes and other values like description, chemical symbol for instance.

And then have a FoodAttribute table containg a record for each Food/Attribute pair.. a classic Many-to-Many join.

Comment: Why would you create 3 layers of references? It makes the structure unnecessarily complicated and takes longer to query for OP's "lots of data". I doubt that they will often find a previously unknown metals in beef.

Comment: Thank you, but would I need a single table just for `FoodId` and `Name`? I think it would'nt have matter if i would merge them.

Comment: @c14L what if a food didn't contain a certain metal.. so you suggested a table with a column for every mineral? that's going to be faster? I'm not an expert on MySQL but that flies against the wind a bit, no?

Comment: @DisplayName123 If the names were in a separate table you wouldn't necessarily need to include that table in your join; the names could be fetched less frequently and cached in the presentation 'layer' , the Id would be enough to resolve the name in the UI and display appropriately.

Comment: No, that's not what I am suggesting. From OP's data, all you need is a row for `food_name` and then `metal_percentage` and `metal_grams` rows for each metal. A simple and fast layout, and sufficient for this use case. Creating separate tables would make sense if you would expect to add new attributes from time to time, but that's unlikely given the topic of the data.

Answer (score 0):

The straghtforward design is

```
-- food FOOD has element ELEMENT associated with PERCENT percent and GRAMS grams
Food(food, element, percent, grams)
```

You don't explain any more that would help us give a more appropriate design. Apparently the weights are of the elements in the foods. Suppose your GRAMS is the weight of an element in some standard weight of food and that a given element is associated with a standard weight per standard weight of food. Then:

```
-- standard weight of food FOOD is PERCENT percent element ELEMENT
Food(food, element, percent)
-- element ELEMENT has weight GRAMS grams per standard weight of food
Weight(element, grams)
```

Then the preceding table value is a function of these tables' values.

You need to express the predicate/meaning for your table(s) (expressed by comments above) clearly enough that a user can look at the current situation and be able to know what values to put in your table(s).